# Почему печЁнка, но чащОба?

Tags: суффиксы

По сути правило одно и то же, должна же быть чащоба с "ё", потому что впереди шипящий, как и в печёнке, но почему тогда так?

Comment: Кажется поняла : чащоба без чередования, а печёнка - печень

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **[Большой толковый словарь](https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0&mode=slovari&l=1&dicts%5B%5D=42)**

**ЧАЩОБА,** -ы; ж. Разг. =**Чаща** (1 зн.). Забраться в чащобу. Непролазная ч. Ч. кустарника. Чащобный, -ая, -ое. Ч-ые заросли.

2. **[Разбор по составу](https://morphemeonline.ru/%D0%A7/%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0#:%7E:text=%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%3A%20%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%89%20%E2%80%94%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%2C,%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%2C%20%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%BE%D0%B1%20%E2%80%94%20%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0):**

   ```
   Части слова: чащ/об/а
   Состав слова:
   чащ — корень,
   об — суффикс,
   а — окончание,
   чащоб — основа слова.
   ```
3. В слове ***чащоба*** в суффиксе существительного  ***ОБ*** пишется ***О***, а в корне слова ***печенка*** пишется ***Е*** при наличии чередования ***Е/Ё***: ***печень — печенка***.

Запомнить: ***учёба.***